# Can someone check what is wrong with my html audio code?

Tags: html, css, audio

Can someone explain why my audio loop isn't working?

Here is my audio code, when it runs I hear nothing on the webpage.

`<audio loop autoplay>
      <source src="/assets/Music/smwtrap.mp3">
    </audio>`

I've tried multiple things, like changing the mp3 and such. My audio used to work but one day just stopped.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is OK.

First, check if the MP3 file exists in that directory in your server.

It might be your browser that doesn't support audio tag. Edit your code like the following, and then reload the page.

```
<audio loop autoplay>
<source src="/assets/Music/smwtrap.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Also try different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [controls](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_controls.asp) attribute to try and play it more than once while troubleshooting. Ensure you have the correct file path in `<source src="/assets/Music/smwtrap.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">`.

If you use the `controls` attribute, and it has 0 as the duration, then its probably not pointing to the file properly.

Comment: Only rarely does whitespace in the HTML make any difference (for example, between `<pre>` tags it would matter). In this case, everything could be all on one line or it could be widely spaced out with the indentation all over the place. The result would be exactly the same either way.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the code was alright, for some reason my browser stopped auto playing audio and I had to change it in the settings, thanks for all the help